# Use claim token in ASMX WebService Request

Tags: asp.net, soap, asmx, claims-based-identity, adfs

I have an ASP.Net Web App which is secured using claims based authentication, currently the IP is Azure ACS, which in turn calls my domain's ADFS (but in theory it could be many different types, e,g, Google, Facebook etc.).

The Web App exposes an endpoint `Service.asmx` which is also secured using the claims authentication.

I found [this blog post](http://leandrob.com/2012/02/request-a-token-from-adfs-using-ws-trust-from-ios-objective-c-iphone-ipad-android-java-node-js-or-any-platform-or-language/) which shows me how to call an IP and return a Request Security Token Response containing my claims.

Once I have acquired this token, how can I use this Request Security Token Response in subsequent web-service calls to the service?

Can this be done using the proxy classes generated by adding a web-reference in VS / wsdl.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ASMX does not have this ability. It is a legacy technology and should not be used for new development.

Comment: Any links on how to do this with other technologies (e.g. WCF)